# UITextView output in \n format - swift

Tags: swift

I enter the text data in UITextView. I am adding multiple lines to UITextView. The output I get from TextView is as follows: Optional("Line1 line2 Line3"). But I want to print it out as follows: "Line1 \ nLine \ 2Line \ 3".
So when I add line text, I want to see the output \ n

I don't want it to be optional, but var text: String! When I do it, Optional does not appear, but this time \ n disappears. I want to see the \ n output on the lines

```
 @IBOutlet weak var textInputArea: UITextView!
  var text : String?
  text = textInputArea.text
        var new = text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\n", options: .regularExpression)
        let jsString = "createText('\(newString)')"
```

Comment: Do you want the print result of `text` be `line1\n line2\n line3\n`? Please clarify more!

Comment: Yes, I want the text printing result to be line1 \ n line2 \ n line3 \ n. @Coder

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the printed result of `text` to be `line1\nline2\nline3`

```
let text = "line1" + "\\n" +  "line2" +  "\\n" + "line3"
 print (text)
```

Output:

```
line1\nline2\nline3
```

Comment: I want the output of the text entered in the TextView to be like this. Not the way you do.